# Counting the number of rows in a table

Tags: mysql, count

What's the syntax for getting the total number of rows in a particular table in a MySQL database?

Answer (score 11):

I've always done

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table
```

The above will you give you the total count of all rows.

You could just as easily tack on a WHERE clause to get the count of some subset

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE foo = 'bar'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM table_name
```