# Mysql count number of rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql

i've tried alot of different examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600233/counting-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table-using-mysql), but I cant make it work. There is something wrong with the code and I always end up with `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()`

I took inspiration from that question and did this:

```
session_start();
$con = new mysqli($url, $user, $password, $db);

$group = $_SESSION['group'];
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_groups WHERE group_id =  ?");
$sql->bind_param("i", $group);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
echo $result;
```

My table: user_groups

[image]

What I want is the number 2 since to users are a part of group nr 1 which is the session group id.

When I only did the query in sql:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually pull the result from the resultset.

See [The PHP manual page for `get_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

```
session_start();
$con = new mysqli($url, $user, $password, $db);

$group = $_SESSION['group'];
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM user_groups WHERE group_id =  ?");
$sql->bind_param("i", $group);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['cnt'];
```